# Jest test fails on a react component which uses react-hooks-form with sharing refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

Here is the abstract version of my component

```
const Test = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const mRef = useThirdpartyHook(); // Third party hook returns a ref
  const { ref, ...rest } = register('test');
  return (
    <input
      type="text" 
      name="test" 
      {...rest} 
      ref={(e) => {
        ref(e); 
        mRef.current = e;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Test case

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
import Test from './Test';

describe('<Test> component', () => {
  it('renders default correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = render(
      <FormProvider
        {...{ register: () => jest.fn() }}>
        <Test />
      </FormProvider>
    );
        
    expect(wrapper.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Executing this test throws an error as given below.

```
<Test> component › renders default correctly

    TypeError: ref is not a function
                     ref={(e) => {
                         ref(e);
                         ^
                         mRef.current = e;
                     }}
```

I tried to mock the ref as function but it didn't help. It would be great if anyone can throw some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register` is a function that returns props the input needs. You are mocking the `register` function, but it still needs to return everything the component is consuming or passing on. Specifically it seems you need to return a `ref` function for what is returned by the `useFormContext` hook.

Example:

```
describe('<Test> component', () => {
  it('renders default correctly', () => {
    const registerMock = () => ({
      ref: jest.fn(),
      .... mock other necessary bits here
    });

    const wrapper = render(
      <FormProvider
        {...{ register: registerMock }}
      >
        <Test />
      </FormProvider>
    );
        
    expect(wrapper.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thank you very much for your response. After updating the code as per the suggestion given by you , I am getting ```register is not a function``` error.

Comment: @user3362908 Oops, sorry, yeah, just make `registerMock` a function that returns an object with the mocked form elements that you need. I've updated my answer. Sorry for any confusion caused on my part.